# are F# ranges evaluated at compile time or run time

Tags: f#, range

the (..) and (.. ..) operators in F# are unrolled at some point, is that a compile time operation or a run time operation?

in either case, what are the performance of this? i.e. is it possible to build a custom function that does those operations faster?

Comment: Write it, compile it, and check it out with Reflector. If you see it unrolled...it's compile time. If not, it's runtime (I'd try it but I don't have the tools at the moment).

Comment: If you're asking if it's possible to build a custom function to evalute a comprehension faster than the feature built into the language--well, maybe.  Like most things in software development, the answer would depend on context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the reply from *kvb* answers most of the concerns. However, I think that a more precise answer is that ranges are evaluated **lazily at runtime**. Here are some more details how ranges work...

When you use for example `1 .. 10` somewhere in your code, it is simply translated to some method call. The call depends on the context and numeric types used.

- For `[ 1 .. 10 ]` or other sequence expressions and `for` loop, the compiler will generate something like `RangeInt32(1, 1, 10)` (the additional parameter is the step).
- When you have something like `obj.[ 1 .. ]` and `obj` is some object that supports slicing (e.g. matrix type), then it will be translated to `obj.GetSlice(Some(1), None)` (note that in this case the upper/lower bound may be missing).

Now it is quite easy to answer your question - it is a method call that will be evaluated at runtime. However it is important to note that the whole range may not need to be evaluated! For example:

```
let nums = seq { 1 .. 10 } |> Seq.take 1
```

The sequence expression will be translated to a call to `RangeInt32`. This will just return a value of type `seq<int>` which is evaluated lazily. The call to `take 1` takes only first element, so only the first number from the range will be needed and evaluated.

I don't think your own implementation of ranges could be any different than the standard one, however you can provide your implementation as a member of an object. Then you could write `myObj.[1 .. 10]` (and the result could be any type you want). To do that, you'll need an instance method `GetSlice`, which is in more detail [discussed here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/07/27/full-release-notes-for-f-1-9-2-7.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Run time.  F# will only very rarely run your code as part of compilation - the only case I can think of is code in `NumericLiteralX` modules.  Besides, in code like this:

```
let f n = [1 .. n]
```

the upper bound isn't even known at compile time.  Of course it's possible that as an implementation detail the F# compiler explicitly unrolls definitions where both bounds are statically known values of a known type (such as `int`), but semantically it should always be the same as if it's done at run time.

Regarding your second question, faster than what?